# React main component is called twice while using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react main component that dispatches redux action on `componentDidMount`, the action will fetch API data.

The problem is: when I start my application my `componentDidMount` and main component are executed twice. So, it makes 2 API calls for each time application loads. API has a limit for the total number of calls I make, I don't want to reach my limit.

I have already tried fixing the issue by removing constructor, using `componentWillMount` problem is not solved.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../redux/actions/fetchActions';
import TableHeader from './tableHeader';

class Main extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("mounted");

        // this.props.dispatch(actions.fetchall("market_cap"));
    }
    render() {
        console.log("rendered");
        //  console.log(this.props.cdata);
        //  console.log(this.props.cdata.data.data_available);

        return <div className="">
            <TableHeader {...this.props} />
        </div>
    }
}

export default Main;
```

///actions

```
    import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchall(sort) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https:-----------`)
            .then(function (response) {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'FETCH_DATA',
                    payload: response.data
                })
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
}
```

//reducer

```
let initialState = {
    coins: [],
    data_available: false,

};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_DATA':
            return {
                ...state,
                coins: action.payload,
                data_available: true

            }
        default: return state;
    }

}
```

//rootreducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import DataReducer from './dataReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    data: DataReducer
});
```

////index

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import MapStateToProps from './components/mapStateToProps';
import rootReducer from './redux/reducers/rootReducer';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
//const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middleware));

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><MapStateToProps/></Provider>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

console image is posted for reference "rendered" is logged inside main component

"runned1" is logged inside main-subcomponent

"mounted" logged inside componentDidMount

"[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can work around this by providing some additional logic in your `componentDidmount`. You should also make use of your component `state`.

Write something like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        mounted: false
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    if(!this.state.mounted){
        this.props.dispatchmyAction()
        this.setState({
            mounted: true
        })
    }
}
```

This essentially says, if your component has already mounted once, then you will not make your action creator request.

Comment: Using state did not change anything

Answer (score 1):

If you watch your `console.log` carefully you can notice that your HMR `Hot Module Reloading` -plugin, re-mounts your component and this is the main reason behind this occurrence.

What this plugin does, is that it watches for your bundles code changes and on every time you save re-renders your component. There has been a lot of discussion as well that this plugin does not work all cases as expected.

Here is some material you might consider to go trough if you wish to use HMR.

Writing about HMR - 
https://codeburst.io/react-hot-loader-considered-harmful-321fe3b6ca74

User guide for HMR - 
https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpacks-hmr-react-hot-loader-the-missing-manual-232336dc0d96

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved when I removed webpack from the project. But can anyone answer how can I solve this while still using the webpack.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.